# Is there a way to align the footnote mark with the top of the footnote text?

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
%%Footnote Mods%%
\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Sample text%
%
\footnote{Footnote text}
%
\end{document}
```

How do I align the top of the footnote mark with the top of the footnote text (in the MWE, I want to have the top of the "1" flush with the "F")?

New error: when implementing Werner's (great) solution I ran into an error when trying to add anything with a "\" in it into the footnote text.

Observe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% Patch \scr@saved@footnotetext to extract first character of footnote and store         in \fnfirstchar
\patchcmd{\scr@saved@footnotetext}% <cmd>
  {\@makefntext}% <search>
    {\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\fnfirstchar]\@makefntext}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{%
  \settoheight{\@tempdima}{\fnfirstchar}% Height of first character in footnote
  \settoheight{\@tempdimb}{$\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark$}% Height of footnote mark
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\@tempdima-\@tempdimb}{$\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark$}}
\makeatother

Sample text\footnote{Footnote text: \S modified}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to this is that "exact placement" is not always possible. Why? It is important to note that TeX works with boxes and not characters. Each character has a bounding box that defines its horizontal and vertical size/structure. So, alignment of elements can only be done up to the precision of these boxes. In that sense, the best you can do is probably:

```
\makeatletter
\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{%
  \settoheight{\@tempdima}{F}% Height of F
  \settoheight{\@tempdimb}{$\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark$}% Height of footnote mark
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\@tempdima-\@tempdimb}{$\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark$}}
\makeatother
```

This stores the height of `F` and a `\scriptstyle` footnote mark in `\@tempdima` and `\@tempdimb`, respectively (these are scratch registers). Then it raises the footnotemark (given by `\thefootnotemark`) to the correct height. The output is not as expected, due to the "boxing restrictions." Here's a minimal example showing the different outputs, just as an example. It is also updated to capture the first character of the footnote (rather than fixing it to the character `F`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% Patch \scr@saved@footnotetext to extract first character of footnote and store in \fnfirstchar
\patchcmd{\scr@saved@footnotetext}% <cmd>
  {\@makefntext}% <search>
    {\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\fnfirstchar]\@makefntext}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
\begin{document}

% Original footnote modification
\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
Sample text\footnote{Footnote text: original}.

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}% Restore counter value

\makeatletter
\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{%
  \settoheight{\@tempdima}{\fnfirstchar}% Height of first character in footnote
  \settoheight{\@tempdimb}{$\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark$}% Height of footnote mark
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\@tempdima-\@tempdimb}{$\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark$}}
\makeatother

Sample text\footnote{Footnote text: modified}.

\end{document}
```

[`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) captures the first character of the footnote (via `\StrLeft`) and stores it in `\fnfirstchar`, while [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patches the appropriate command by inserting the extraction in the right spot (*after* the footnote text has been read, but *before* it is being typeset).

As illustration, boxing the footnote mark and `F` character shows that they're placed at the same height (as TeX sees it):

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to modify your (great) suggestion to always set to the height of the letter that immediately follows the footnote mark as opposed to the letter "F"?

Comment: @Dennis: I've updated my answer to incorporate such a modification. Note that you might get unexpected results if you start your footnote with a space.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. Your MWE is working fine for me, but when I change it to add anything with a "\" in it, I get an error. I've updated my question to provide an MWE of the error.

Comment: @Dennis: As of now, I'm not sure how to solve the problem... I noticed you [posted something on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2698/5764).

Comment: Yes I did, I wasn't sure whether it was appropriate to keep bugging you for help or whether this warranted a new question.

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: @Dennis: This is an encoding issue. You can either add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble, or save the contents in a box and the use the box in your footnote. For example, `\newsavebox{\footnotebox}\begin{lrbox}{\footnotebox}\footnotesize\S\end{lrbox}` and then use `\footnote{Here is a \usebox{\footnotebox} footnote.}`.

Answer (score 6):

A less technical but more typographical way might be to use the package [`superiors`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/superiors). Quoting from the manual:

> The default behavior of footnote and endnote markers in LaTeX is to
>   print the number as if it were a mathematical superscript. In most
>   cases, this means the size is about 70% of the normal lining figure
>   and the top is somewhat above the tops of capital letters. In many
>   cases, the superscript figure is simply reduced in all dimensions by
>   about 70%, making them appear rather slight, though overly tall. [...]
>
> As an alternative, one may use superior
>   figures—small figures, usually 50% to 60% of the height of lining
>   figures, like 1234567890. Commonly, they are designed so that the tops
>   of the numbers are aligned with the tops of the capital letters in the
>   font, though sometimes a little higher, corresponding to the ascender
>   height.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
%%Footnote Mods%%
\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{\textsu{\thefootnotemark}\,}
%%%%%%
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[supstfm=ntxsups,supspaced=.06em]{superiors}
\begin{document}

Sample text%
%
\footnote{Footnote text}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally the package option `raised=<dim>` would allow to adjust the vertical position of the superscript numbers. Of course the vertical position would not depend on following characters. (But what if the following token is a small `a` or a control sequence anyway?)

Comment: This seems to be roughly what I'm looking for. At a first pass I can't get it to do _exactly_ what I want but that's a problem for another day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see the need to load any package in Werner's solution. Both *etoolbox* and *xstring* are relatively large packages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\let\@tempa\scr@saved@footnotetext
\edef\@tempa{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand\scr@saved@footnotetext##1{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\@tempa{#1}}%
    \unexpanded{\fngetfirstchar\fnfirstchar{#1}}%
  }%
}
\@tempa
\def\fngetfirstchar#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@tempa##1##2\fn@nil{\endgroup\gdef#1{##1}}%
  \expandafter\@tempa#2\fn@nil
}
\def\usenewfootnotestyle{%
  \deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\s\ensuremath
    \settoheight{\@tempdima}{\fnfirstchar}%
    \settoheight{\@tempdimb}{\s{\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark}}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\@tempdima-\@tempdimb}{\s{\scriptstyle\thefootnotemark}}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% Original footnote style:
\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
Sample text\footnote{Footnote text: original}.
\par
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
% Change footnote style:
\usenewfootnotestyle

Sample text\footnote{Footnote text: modified}.
\end{document}
```